# Core Data One-To-Many Fetch Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Okay I have a one-to-many relationship in core data.  A Meal can consists of many different Food.  My code doesn't quite seem to be working in the Fetch Controller.  I can say this with confidence, the self.meal is the current Meal I am trying to fetch.  I am sharing the context through out the application.

The problem I am having is that the application is displaying foods but it doesn't quite seem to match up against what should be inside of a Meal.  As soon as I add a food, it immediately displays that, even if it is not inside of the Meal.

Any help or suggestion, I am doing this fetch correctly.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController 
{       
    self.context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Food" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    NSPredicate *foodPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"meals == %@", self.meal];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:foodPredicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];


    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    [fetchRequest release];
    [theFetchedResultsController release];

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: I've looked at your `NSFetchedResultsController` code an cannot find anything wrong with it.  Is the errant behavior taking place irrespective of what `self.meal` contains?  There's no chance that `self.meal` is nil when you see the spurious data, right?  Or, could you have spurious data in the persistent store left over from prior code experiments?  If so, manually deleting the store file can help.

Comment: I'll have to run through each line of code, but I do believe self.meal never becomes nil

Comment: Could you paste a bit more code.   Doesn't seem to be anything wrong here.

Comment: Check out if this helps u.Thanks!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010000/how-to-fetch-one-to-many-relationship-in-core-data

Comment: @alanduncan you were right, the self.meal at one point was nil, which was causing the weird activity.  If you want to make that an answer, i'll accept it for you.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Vikings1201 you are welcome. I put in an answer so it comes of the the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `self.meals` were `nil` then the `NSFetchedResultsController` would return `Food`s that are not part of a `Meal`, thereby accounting for the behavior you're noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate is incorrect. You should not be comparing `meals`, which is a `NSSet` of `Meal` objects, to a single `meal`. You need to see if the `meals` set on the `Food` object contains that meal.

```
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ in meals", self.meal]
```

Comment: I went ahead and tried this out, but it did not work. Thanks for the input though.